# UITextView auto expand in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` at the last row of `UITableView`. I want to auto expand the `UITextView` according to the text which is working fine. But as the `UITextView` expands, the `UITableViewCell` should also expand. I tried `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in `textViewDidChange` but that again and again reloads the cell causing the `UITextView` `resignFirstResponder`.
This is the code :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
    textView.frame = frame;
    [tableMessageDetail beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(int)txtReplyBottom.tag inSection:0];
    [tableMessageDetail reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableMessageDetail endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Why do u add the textView in the last row in UITabeView? I suggest setting it as TableViewFooter

Comment: @HossamGhareeb : And how do you suggest to update the height of TableViewFooter ?

Comment: What about trying to update the footer frame to the same frame of your textView? I'm not sure it that will work, but give it a shot

Comment: so grab it like this `footer = tableView.tableFooterView` then update its height. Then assign it again `tableView.tableFooterView = footer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gif

[image]

Cell-AutoLayout

I add a height constraint with >= 50

[image]

Code

```
@interface SelfSizingCell ()<UITextViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textview;

@end
@implementation SelfSizingCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    self.textview.delegate = self;
    self.textview.scrollEnabled = false;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    CGFloat height = size.height;
   if (height < 50) {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = 50;
    }else{
       self.heightConstraint.constant = height;
    }
   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
 }
@end
```

.h

```
@interface SelfSizingCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak,nonatomic)UITableView * tableView;

@end
```

And tableviewController

```
@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SelfSizingCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 }
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SelfSizingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tableView = self.tableView;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: UITextView isn't created in IB. I am creating it programmatically.

Comment: @Nitish, create a HeightConstraint and update then height.
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)